# IBM Bladecenter S with 6-Disk Storage Module with new Hard Drives

Tags: ibm, bladecenter

We have IBM Bladecenter S with 6-Disk Storage Module and are looking to add new larger drives, as IBM no longer supply and support this system.

Has anyone tried to add off the shelf hard drives either SAS or SATA to this system with success.

Comment: welcome, we are sorry but unsupported systems are off topic, while also product suggestions are also not on topic mostly look into the manual or ask IBM to provide the last known working storage. there might also be a chance that you could contact purestorage as they have a right size guarantee... might helpful in your case